# How to typealias methods in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, type-alias

I'm trying to convert my Swift 2+ codes to Swift 3. I have some `typealias` code references which I'm not able to fix per Swift 3 syntax requirement.

```
typealias UpdateProcessHandler = (_ value:Double) -> Void

class StartUploadingProcess: Operation
{
    ...
    fileprivate var updateHandler: UpdateProcessHandler!

    init(filePath: String, updateHandler:@escaping UpdateProcessHandler)
    {
        self.updateHandler = updateHandler
        ...
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
    {
        ...
        self.updateHandler(value: self.progress.fractionCompleted)
        ...
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to call the method `self.updateHandler`, XCode report compiler error: `Cannot call value of non-function type 'UpdateProcessHandler!'`

Any reason why I'm having this or how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.updateHandler(self.progress.fractionCompleted)
```

Comment: It does honor it. The underscore in the function signature means that there is no label for `value`.